# Retrofit 2 dependencies issue

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp, okio

I am using retrofit 2 library for network calls.Project is not builing up even after adding dependencies. I have attached the screenshot.

[image]
 [image]

Comment: make sure u are connected to internet before u resolve, also clarify the versions of repo, some might have been removed, or in compatible

Comment: is it checked?? File->Settings->Gradle.
Look at the "Offline work" inbox, if it's checked u uncheck and try to sync again.

Comment: Show your main build.gradle

Comment: @RonakThakkar it is unchecked and have tried to sync it multiple times

Comment: @RohanPawar I have added the screenshot..

Answer (score 0):

In your `Fame-Circle`'s project level `build.gradle` file (The recently added screenshot),

add:

```
maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
```

which should now look like:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add below line inside your Frame-Circle main gradle file

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have added above repos .Its still showing the same error.

Comment: change your annotation processors compile version to the latest

Comment: did you add maven urls under allprojects?